# Redirecting multiple subdomains to a static site on Google Cloud Storage with Cloud DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, cname-record, google-cloud-platform, a-record

I am trying to migrate my website from a wordpress site to a static site.

I have added all my static assets to a bucket on google cloud storage and successfully pointed [static.mildfuzz.com](http://static.mildfuzz.com) to that bucket using a `CNAME`. All is good.

How can I redirect both `mildfuzz.com` and `www.mildfuzz.com` to the same bucket? My thought was to use `ALIAS` or `URL`, but they do not seem available using Google Cloud DNS service. I then thought maybe use a `CNAME`, but I was concerned that assigning a `CNAME` to `mildfuzz.com` would mess with my `MX` records.

At the moment my static site is also being served by a `Compute Engine` VM, so that I can use an `A` record pointing to an IP, but I would very much like to be able to turn this VM off, as that is the point of switching to a static site in the first place!

Comment: One of the answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731252/how-to-host-an-entire-site-on-google-cloud-storage indicates it's possible via Google's "synthetic records". https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6069273?hl=en

Comment: Google's "synthetic records" is unique to Google Domains, which is not available to UK users :(

Comment: That sucks. You may have to use a different DNS provider for now.

Comment: Yeah, looked at AWS DNS and it looks the same deal. Hmm... I just want to implement a redirect. Can't be this hard?!

Comment: It's not that hard, but AWS/Google basically just implement it for their own systems. DNSSimple (https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/alias-record/) and CloudFlare (https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169056-CNAME-Flattening-RFC-compliant-support-for-CNAME-at-the-root) offer CNAME-like apex records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, there is no real way of routing multiple domains including a naked domain to a single bucket with the use of Cloud DNS that applies globally.

Cloud DNS does not currently offer `ALIAS` or `URL` records and the using a `CNAME` record will likely affect your `MX` records.

This seems like an excellent feature.  I would suggest [filing a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/issues/entry) on the Google Cloud Platform public issue tracker with the **Product-CloudDNS** label.  Feel free to comment with a link if you do so here so others can follow through and support the request.

Comment: I just used cloudns in the end. Great service.

Comment: Happy to hear it!  Feel free to post that as an answer yourself and accept it as a solution so this is considered to be answered.

Comment: TBH It's not the answer to the question. I would have preferred to keep everything within google and still would if it became possible. I will leave open till that answer it found.

Comment: If I understood the question correctly that you wish to redirect both the subdomain **www** and the naked domain to the same bucket using only Google Cloud DNS and the built-in features of the Google Cloud Platform, then the answer is that ***this is not possible*** which is generally considered [an acceptable answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261168/is-this-is-not-possible-an-acceptable-answer).  Since there are no public plans for Google Cloud DNS to support `ALIAS` records, this question would otherwise be unanswerable.

Comment: Fair point. Have a tick.